# signalR Cross Domain with tcp protocol used as selfhosted server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

[image: services host from which i am trying to access client method]

[image: view]
[image: global.asax]

[image: Error]

I am trying to implement the Cross-domain calls with SignalR File version 1.1.20525.0 . I have my views in  (localhost:1598) and the 'service' in  (localhost:8040).

But i am getting this error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load net.tcp://localhost:8040/signalr/negotiate?_=1375725058645. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. " .Where am i doing it wrong or what should i add in my project?

My hub is in the same project where my views are so should i move them to service project folder?

Comment: Isn't the error self-explanatory?

Comment: @AbhishekNanda   
well i can't get it ...i am very new to this can you please help?